# Адаптивное изображение

Tags: css, css3

Например для создания адаптивного изображения используется способ представленный ниже.

1. Img - строчный элемент, как к нему может применяться свойство *height*?
2. Если оно допустимо, а *auto* это значение по умолчанию, то для чего оно указывается?

```css
.container {
 width: 800px;
 max-width: 90%;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: что бы наверняка

Comment: А почему бы просто не применить `background-size` с тем же `cover` или `contain`. И мороки не будет. с шириной и высотой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких блочных и строчных элементов в html давно нет. Вот хорошая [статья](http://css-live.ru/articles/blochnyx-i-strochnyx-elementov-v-html-bolshe-net.html) на эту тему.

Чтобы понять, насколько смешно считать img строчным элементом, давайте вспомним, что по древнему  стандарту,  строчные элементы не имеют ширины. Где логика вообще?

В приведенном вами коде ширина изображения устанавливается в 100% от родительского блока, а указание высоты в auto нужно для того, чтобы сохранить его пропорции при изменении ширины.